# How to create NATS push consumer using jscontext.newConsumer() in Golang

Tags: go, nats.io, nats-jetstream

While creating js context [AddConsumer](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/nats-io/nats.go#JetStreamManager)(topic.ID(), &nats.ConsumerConfig{}) creating pull consumer, Is there any way to create a push consumer using [addconsumer](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/nats-io/nats.go#JetStreamManager)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is very bad about this part, and the errors are not very descriptive. I spent hours figuring it out. Here is what I found...

To create a push consumer using `AddConsumer` you must provide the `DeliverySubject` parameter, it can be anything, and for simplicity it can be the same as the consumer name. The documentation for this part is very bad and does not explain how it should be used.

The following is a full working example that creates a consumer and subscribes to certain subject from that consumer.

```golang
nc, err := nats.Connect("nats://localhost:4222")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("could not connect to nats: %s", err)
}

js, err := nc.JetStream()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Could not get jetstream:", err)
}

streamName := "TEST_STREAM"
_, err = js.AddStream(&nats.StreamConfig{
    Name:      streamName,
    Subjects:  []string{"test.>"},
    Retention: nats.InterestPolicy,
    Replicas:  1,
})

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error creating stream %q: %s\n", streamName, err)
    return
}

groupName := "group-1"
consumerName := fmt.Sprintf("%s-consumer", groupName)
_, err = js.AddConsumer(
    streamName,
    &nats.ConsumerConfig{
        Name:           consumerName,
        Durable:        consumerName,
        DeliverSubject: consumerName,
        DeliverGroup:   groupName,
    },
)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error creating consumer %q: %s\n", consumerName, err)
    return
}

subject := "test.resource.created"
_, err = js.QueueSubscribe(
    subject,
    groupName,
    func(msg *nats.Msg) { 
        fmt.Printf("Jetstream - received %q: %q\n", msg.Subject, msg.Data) 
    },
    nats.Bind(streamName, consumerName),
)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error subscribing to %q: %s\n", subject, err)
}
```

**delivery group** is provided so that several app instances can subscribe to the same consumer and the event will only be delivered to one of them (at random). That is, if you want to scale the app horizontally.

If you want to restrict what events the consumer receives. Then you should provide `SubjectFilter` to consumer config. Each consumer will persist **all events** that their filter matches, or all the events from the stream if no filter is provided.

After creating the consumer, You can then subscribe to it using any JetStream subscribe method (`js.SubscribeSync`, `js.QueueSubscribeSync`, `js.Subscribe`, `js.QueueSubscribe`, ...) but you **MUST** provide nats option to bind the subscription to a consumer, this is done using `nats.Bind(streamName, consumerName)`

You can leave the subject name an empty string when subscribing to subscribe to all events from the consumer.

Answer (score -1):

Create a Consumer.

```golang
js.AddConsumer("ORDERS", &nats.ConsumerConfig{
    Durable: "MONITOR",
})
```

AddConsumer adds a consumer to a stream.

```golang
AddConsumer(stream string, cfg *ConsumerConfig, opts ...JSOpt) (*ConsumerInfo, error)
```

Comment: This creates a pull consumer, that causes an error when attempting to use it with `js.Subscribe` or `js.QueueSubscribe`